# How to remove the notifications of other people's commits in repos that I no longer contribute to, from my GitHub activity stream?

Tags: github

When I go to github.com, I see:

- On the left side: a list of all my repositories PLUS all repositories that I recently contributed to with commits or pull requests or comments.
- In the middle: a list of all activities on all the repositories in the list of the previous bullet point.

Some of the repositories are from my previous employer, where I made commits until about two weeks ago. The commit activity there is very high and I don't want to see those commits because they are no longer relevant for me. How do make sure that I no longer see that activity?

As a test I have done the following:

- There is a person that I follow on Github.
- I do not follow any of their repositories.
- I have never contributed in any of their repositories.
- I see their commits on all of their repositories appear on my Github page.
- I have unfollowed that person.
- Their commit activity still appears on my Github page.

The only way I found so far to remove their activity from my Github page, is to **BLOCK** them. Which is quite extreme...

Even when blocking a PERSON, I still see the repos in the list on the left.

Question to the people reading this question: should I add screenshots to clarify?

Comment: I am not watching any repositories at all, the link you gave me, does not show any repositories at all. I still see the activity from other people on repos that I have contributed to in the past. So your answer is wrong or incomplete.